# ChartJS with dates on the X axis not displaying any graph

Tags: chart.js, momentjs, vue-chartjs

I have a Vue.JS project getting data from a REST API (mine, so I can modify it if needed). This data is formatted for Chart.JS.
I am supposed to display a graph with 3 datasets, 2 of type line with the same X values, but 1 of type bar with different X values (that's why I don't want to specify labels). Whatever, all the X values are dates, so I would like only 1 X axis for all the curves.

I am using datasets with (x,y) data format :

- x is an ISO8601 date
- y is a float

My problem is that NOTHING is displayed at all...could anyone help me please, I don't understand why. I feel like having done things right. I saw somewhere that I needed to include momentjs, but in the official documentation they say that it is not the case. I bet that the problems come from the dates because I tried changing the y values, and the 2 y axis bounds are modified (so y values are understood). I also tried addind the "xAxisID" option, nothing changed.

Here is a sample of my data (normally hundreds of values) :

```
{
  "type": "line",
  "data": {
    "datasets": [
      {
        "label": "Température",
        "borderColor": "red",
        "backgroundColor": "red",
        "fill": false,
        "data": [
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T15:38:47.933711",
            "y": 2.8224692
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T15:48:47.490669",
            "y": 33.63129
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T15:58:48.182698",
            "y": 40.540405
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T16:08:47.829882",
            "y": 3.0312533
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T16:18:47.489026",
            "y": 49.145626
          }
        ],
        "yAxisID": "yAxeTemperature"
      },
      {
        "label": "Humidité",
        "borderColor": "blue",
        "backgroundColor": "blue",
        "fill": false,
        "data": [
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T15:38:47.933711",
            "y": 33.980587
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T15:48:47.490669",
            "y": 2.0313625
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T15:58:48.182698",
            "y": 24.249685
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T16:08:47.829882",
            "y": 7.4426904
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T16:18:47.489026",
            "y": 2.6335742
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T16:28:48.175547",
            "y": 25.92827
          }
        ],
        "yAxisID": "yAxeHumidite"
      }
    ]
  },
  "options": {
    "responsive": true,
    "hoverMode": "index",
    "stacked": false,
    "title": null,
    "scales": {
      "xAxes": [
        {
          "type": "time",
          "display": true,
          "position": "bottom",
          "id": "xAxeTime",
          "scaleLabel": {
            "display": true,
            "labelString": "Temps",
            "fontColor": "black"
          },
          "time": {
            "unit": "minute",
            "parser": "moment.ISO_8601",
            "tooltipFormat": "ll"
          }
        }
      ],
      "yAxes": [
        {
          "type": "linear",
          "display": true,
          "position": "left",
          "id": "yAxeTemperature",
          "scaleLabel": {
            "display": true,
            "labelString": "Température",
            "fontColor": "red"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "linear",
          "display": true,
          "position": "left",
          "id": "yAxeHumidite",
          "scaleLabel": {
            "display": true,
            "labelString": "Humidité",
            "fontColor": "blue"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how my chart is created (using vue-chartjs and chart.js) :

```
createChart(chartId : string, chartData : GrapheBean) {
      const ctx = document.getElementById(chartId);
      // @ts-ignore
      const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: chartData.type,
        data: chartData.data,
        options: chartData.options,
      });
    }
```

Here is the result :

[image]

I am stuck now, even if still trying things with little hope. Thanks a lot in advance for the ones who could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should remove the option `xAxes.time.parser`. It is not needed when the dates are of ISO8601 format.

Further Chart.js effectively internally uses Moment.js for the functionality of the [time axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

Please have a look at your amended code in a pure JavaScript version.

```js
const chartData = {
  "type": "line",
  "data": {
    "datasets": [{
        "label": "Température",
        "borderColor": "red",
        "backgroundColor": "red",
        "fill": false,
        "data": [{
            "x": "2020-07-05T15:38:47.933711",
            "y": 2.8224692
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T15:48:47.490669",
            "y": 33.63129
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T15:58:48.182698",
            "y": 40.540405
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T16:08:47.829882",
            "y": 3.0312533
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T16:18:47.489026",
            "y": 49.145626
          }
        ],
        "yAxisID": "yAxeTemperature"
      },
      {
        "label": "Humidité",
        "borderColor": "blue",
        "backgroundColor": "blue",
        "fill": false,
        "data": [{
            "x": "2020-07-05T15:38:47.933711",
            "y": 33.980587
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T15:48:47.490669",
            "y": 2.0313625
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T15:58:48.182698",
            "y": 24.249685
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T16:08:47.829882",
            "y": 7.4426904
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T16:18:47.489026",
            "y": 2.6335742
          },
          {
            "x": "2020-07-05T16:28:48.175547",
            "y": 25.92827
          }
        ],
        "yAxisID": "yAxeHumidite"
      }
    ]
  },
  "options": {
    "responsive": true,
    "hoverMode": "index",
    "stacked": false,
    "title": null,
    "scales": {
      "xAxes": [{
        "type": "time",
        "display": true,
        "position": "bottom",
        "id": "xAxeTime",
        "scaleLabel": {
          "display": true,
          "labelString": "Temps",
          "fontColor": "black"
        },
        "time": {
          "unit": "minute",
          // "parser": "moment.ISO_8601", -> remove this line
          "tooltipFormat": "ll"
        }
      }],
      "yAxes": [{
          "type": "linear",
          "display": true,
          "position": "left",
          "id": "yAxeTemperature",
          "scaleLabel": {
            "display": true,
            "labelString": "Température",
            "fontColor": "red"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "linear",
          "display": true,
          "position": "left",
          "id": "yAxeHumidite",
          "scaleLabel": {
            "display": true,
            "labelString": "Humidité",
            "fontColor": "blue"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: chartData.type,
  data: chartData.data,
  options: chartData.options,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="120"></canvas>
```

> In your question you also wrote *"I am supposed to display a graph with 3 datasets, 2 of type line with the same X values, but 1 of type bar with different X values"*. Your code however only defines 2 datasets. In case you're also facing problems with this point, please post a new question for this separate issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot @uminder! You saved my life!
The option xAxes.time.parser was one of the last desperate trials because I did not know about this difference with the bundle version.

Comment: About the third dataset, I was waiting for this to be working before adding more complexity.